# TableRow division

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout, tablerow

Well, my app has a tablelayout with a lot of tablerows, but how can I put a division between them? Eg: a tablerow, after that a line, after that another tablerow and so on. Is there some property for that?

Answer (score 13):

There is in Android 3.0 and forward. On your TableLayout:

```
android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
android:showDividers="middle"
```

Before Android 3.0 you should be able to use dummy views as dividers between each row like this:

```
<View android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
```